# How to find the occurrence of k-mers in a list of DNA sequences

Tags: sequences, find-occurrences

I want to scan a list of DNA sequences against a list of given k-mers; each element on the k-mer list is a set of similar k-mers of equal length, they look like

myKmer1=c("TATGGGTTT", "TAAGGGTTT", ...,"CAAGGGTTT")

...

myKmer10=c("GGATTCCAG","CCATTCTTT",..., "CGATTCCTT")

What software/ R-script are available to attain the occurrences of list of k-mers on each sequence--the outcome should be a table looks like:

k-mers occurrence table1: showing the counts of k-mer in the sequences

myKmer1 myKmer2 ...myKmer10

seq1 2 0 3

seq2 1 3 0

...

seq1000 0 1 0

k-mers occurrence table2: showing the location of k-mer in the sequences

myKmer1 myKmer2 ...myKmer10

seq1 111, 888 0 123,456,3333

seq2 123 111,223,333 0

...

seq1000 0 1234 0

Comment: You might get a better response for this type of question on Biostars

Answer (score 1):

If the kmers that you are looking for are the same length then you could use [Jellyfish](http://www.cbcb.umd.edu/software/jellyfish/) with the dump subcommand to give you the counts of all kmers of length k. You could then parse the output for your specific kmers. See also the [Jellyfish user guide](ftp://ftp.genome.umd.edu/pub/jellyfish/JellyfishUserGuide.pdf).